# Show date in asp:datagrid in European format

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

ASP.NET page.  Asp:DataGrid.   A column asp:BoundColumn has DataFormatString="{0:d}"  This shows date in American format.
How do you change the value in the DataFormatString to show the date in European format?

Answer (score 1):

You can just shove in any format you want, say like:

```
 DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did try this approach and it works.  I was hoping that I would find an approach that would work for both the US and GB dates.